# Multiple Training Jobs in One Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Can we train multiple models using one Sagemaker Instance? We are currently having 7 Models for different problems. Can we use one instance for all the models?

Answer (score 0):

According to the AWS Forum, there is no explicit way of doing this.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=837740

The workaround listed down there is

1. Combine the models resulting from training into a single tar file
2. Have your container load all the models when it starts up
3. In your HTTP requests for inference include a model id or some such as part of the data
4. Implement logic in your container to choose the model based on the request data.

Further details are in the forum thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you're discussing inference, rather than training, then [Deploying more than one model to your Endpoint is currently *doable* with TensoFlow](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/deploying_tensorflow_serving.rst#deploying-more-than-one-model-to-your-endpoint). But not with other frameworks.

Of course you can bring your own container, and then everything is possible.